# Velocity Factor in Transmission Line

Tags: transmission-line, characteristic-impedance

For a lossless line, you have \$Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ and \$VF=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{LC}}\$.

For a line with R, L, G and C parameters, we have \$Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}}\$. 
But how the formula changes for the VF parameter?

Considering the [coaxial cable example](https://www.picwire.com/technical/tech-papers/velocity-factor/), one could say the VF not only depends on \$Z\$, but also in the geometry of the cable, hence a more real expression for VF do not exist?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lossy transmission line

\$ Z_0 = \frac{\sqrt{R+j\omega L}}{\sqrt{G + j\omega C}} 
\$

Note that for \$ R << \omega L\$ and \$ G << \omega C\$ this reduces to the expression in your question.

Finding the phase velocity of a lossy line is difficult as the propagation constant \$\beta \$ will, in general, be a non linear function of frequency. (Except for a distortionless line that satisfies the [Heaviside Condtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_condition)). This means that the velocity factor is not a very useful metric, except over a narrow band or small distance.

In fact it means that different frequency components of a signal will travel at different speeds, resulting in distortion of the signal and inter-symbol interference in the case of digital communications.

The geometry of the cable determines the R, L, G and C parameters as well as Z and the phase velocity.

**Edit**: I'm not sure if a better general expression than this can be found but the complex propagation constant will be:

\$ \gamma = j\omega \sqrt{LC}  \sqrt{1 - j(\frac{R}{\omega L} + \frac{G}{\omega C}) - \frac{RG}{\omega^2LC}}\$

Then the phase velocity is

\$ v_p = \frac{\omega}{Imaginary(\gamma)}\$

Thus the velocity factor is

\$ \frac{\omega}{c Imaginary(\gamma)} \$

And I don't think the Gamma expression can be decomposed into real and imaginary parts without making approximations.

Comment: My mistake. I am refering to the VF parameter. Check the edit.

Comment: One would expect G close to zero. Also, one would expect to have a VF for a given specific frequency. GIven that, which would be the approximation for the VF?

Comment: The only approximation I've seen used is the one in your original expression

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has the fully-general formula for the characteristic impedance at a given angular frequency \$\omega\$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance

\$Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{R+j\omega{}L}{G+j\omega{}C}}\$

Note that for a lossless line (R=0, G=0), the frequency factor cancels out, but for a lossy line it does not.

I'm not sure about the velocity factor.

Comment: My mistake. I am refering to the VF parameter. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think the velocity factor of coax cable  is related to relative dielectric constant only.

$$V_F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon_R}}
$$

EDIT:
In general case, you would need to calculate C and L for the specific geometry of the transmission line. [See example](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/velocity_factor.pdf)

Also the distance from ground has also some effects on velocity factor. For example an insulated wire used as antenna, has a velocity factor:

$$V_F= \sqrt{\dfrac{\varepsilon\cdot ln\dfrac{4h}{D}+ln\dfrac{D}{d}}{\varepsilon\cdot ln\dfrac{4h}{d}}}$$

Reference: [G4FGQ](https://www.radiobanter.com/antenna/68077-velocity-factor-insulated-antenna-wire.html) and [KB6NU](https://www.kb6nu.com/should-dipoles-made-with-insulated-wire-be-made-shorter/) , my rearrangement

Where \$h\$ is the height above the ground, \$d\$ is conductor diameter, \$D\$ is overall diameter (conductor + insulator).

Comment: Yes, i found that relationship as described in the link. I dont know if that is truth or how this is related with \$Z_0\$ for the general case.